# More efficient way to do the below problem

Tags: python-3.x

```
Limit = int(input('Enter the limit: '))
Number = 1
NumberIncrement = 1
while( NumberIncrement < ( Limit+1 ) ):
    val = NumberIncrement - 1
    space = NumberIncrement
    while ( space < Limit ):
        print(' ',end = '')
        space += 1
    for x in range( Number ,(NumberIncrement+1)  ):
        print( x, end = '')
    while ( val > 0):
        print( val, end = '')
        val -= 1
    print('\n')
    NumberIncrement += 1
NumberIncrement = 1
val1 = Limit
while( Limit > (NumberIncrement-1) ):
    val = Limit - 2
    space = (val1-1) - val
    for x in range( 0, space ):
        print(' ',end = '')
    for x in range( Number ,Limit ):
        print(x, end = '')
    while ( val > 0):
        print( val, end = '')
        val -=1
    print('\n')
    Limit -=1
```

the output is:

Enter the limit: 5

```
    1

   121

  12321

 1234321

123454321

 1234321

  12321

   121

    1
```

I am new to coding and I am looking for different ways to solve the above problem.

Is there a better way to solve this problem using less number of loops in the code.

Answer (score 1):

One sort of halfway concise and elegant approach, using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`str.center`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center):

```
from itertools import chain

def upanddown(n):  # lazy iterator producing 1, 2, ..., n-1, n, n-1, ..., 2, 1
    return chain(range(1, n), range(n, 0, -1))

def diamond(n):
    for i in upanddown(n):
        print(''.join(map(str, upanddown(i))).center(2*n-1))

>>> diamond(5)
    1    
   121   
  12321  
 1234321 
123454321
 1234321 
  12321  
   121   
    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this documentation. You will get an idea.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but I think it kind of works:

```
limit=5

d=[]
s=''

for i in map(str,range(1,limit+1)):
    s += i
    l = s+s[-2::-1]
    ll = ' ' * (limit - len(l) // 2) +l
    d.append(ll)
    print(ll)

for i in d[-2::-1]:
    print(i)
```

You have the additional newlines, I am not sure if they are intended, but you can easily add them back.